# How can a name a New Image() added to a page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, appendchild

I'm adding an image to a page with javascript, like this...

```
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = dataUrl;
 document.body.appendChild(img);
```

On Chrome, if I right click the image and save it, Chrome automatically names it `download.png`
On Firefox, it's called `index.png`.  I'd like to automatically name it something I specify.  Is there something I can add to the code like `img.name = "MyImage.png"` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a usage like this for HTML5.

```
<a href="/path/to/image.jpg" download="file-name.jpg">
```

You must define an attribute named "download" to the image element.

```
img.setAttribute('download', 'file-name.jpg');
```